# Layout not scrollable

Tags: css, sass, vaadin

I am in the process of designing an app using Vaadin / Spring boot and  i have managed to set the background of my app using the following css located within the styles.scss file(within myTheme as per Vaadin):

```
.backgroundImage{

      background: url("img/background4.png") ;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    }
```

which does what it says on the tin, it sets the background image. My problem is that this makes the page no longer scroll able, here is a picture of one of my forms:[image].

Does anyone have any idea where i'm going wrong here? additionally I really want to set this background as the default background for my app. Can anyone advise on how to do this?

I changed the CSS to read:

```
  .backgroundImage{

    background: url("img/background4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

as directed by Mo but i'm now getting a 37 pixel padding? the class constructor looks like this:

```
 public AddEmployeeView() {
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3,2);
        setSizeFull();
        setStyleName("backgroundImage");
        setMargin(false);
        setDefaultComponentAlignment(MIDDLE_CENTER);
        addComponent(aUI.getHeader());
        header.addStyleName("h2");
        addComponent(header);
        Panel topleft = topLeftAndBottom();
        Panel topright = topRight();
        grid.setSizeUndefined();
        grid.addComponent(topleft,0,0,0,1);
        grid.addComponent(topright,1,0,1,1);
        addComponents(grid,generateButtons());

    }
```

[image]

Comment: what is missing padding-bottom ?

Comment: Theres a 37 px padding all around it?

Comment: Where did you apply the background img ?

Comment: added the Java constructor the class extends VerticalLayout and implements View

Comment: Do you want the background img to cover all the app ? or just that component ?

Comment: The entire app? I've tried adding:.v-app{
    background: url("img/background4.png") ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }

Comment: I updated my anwser

Answer (score 0):

Use this css :

```
.backgroundImage{

    background: url("img/background4.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

### Edit

If you want the backgroud img to cover all the app just apply the styles above to `body` or `html` and put that style in the `Global styles`

> Global styles are styles defined in the document scope. Global styles
>   can target document body and any regular DOM contents inside,
>   including the application views

Comment: edited the question with the problem your solution presents when it's changed.